# How to use Either with IO properly?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, akka-http, scala-cats

I have `AkkaHttp` client and `cats` library. I'd like to escape throwing exception, so I wrote this code:

```
class AkkaHttpJokeClient(url: String)(implicit system: ActorSystem) extends JokeClient[IO] {
  override def getJoke(): IO[Either[Throwable, Joke]] = {
    implicit val materializer: ActorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer()
    implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = system.dispatcher

    IO.fromFuture(IO {
      Http()
        .singleRequest(HttpRequest(uri = url))
        .flatMap(Unmarshal(_).to[String])
        .map(x => Try{x.parseJson.convertTo[Joke]}.toEither)
      })
  }
}
```

It works, but I have a few problems with it. The first one is connection problem isn't solved. The second: I think it could be done easier, isn't it? I can't find right methods to do it better.

Comment: "The first one is connection problem isn't solved." What is the problem which is not solved?

Comment: For example connection timeout problem.

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? For example, return `IO[Joke]` from the `getJoke()` and not have nested Either with one more error channel?